# PHP MYSQL How to insert $_POST data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am using the following code to pull all language variables and values form a MySQL database and populate a form for editing:

```
function language() {

    $settings = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `languages`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        ?>

            <div style="float:left;width:250px;padding-left:15px"><label><?php echo $row['id'];?></label></div><div style="float:left;margin-left:0px;"><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['value'];?>" /></div>

        <? php

    }
}
```

I have a rudimentary function to save the changes made in the above form back to the database updating with any changes:

```
function save_language() {

    $post = $_POST;
    $out = array_shift($post);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    foreach($post as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "UPDATE `languages` SET `value`='$value' WHERE `id`='$key'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    if ($result) {
        echo "Language Settings Updated";
    }

}
```

This method works but it is very slow.  I am new to coding and I am sure I am overlooking something simple that would speed up the saving process.

Comment: What do you mean with slow?

Comment: Switch to PDO as mysql is deprecated. Your query is also prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your query actually shouldn't be working because the connection is out of scope of the function. The correct way to pass the connection would be through the function:

```
function language( $conn ) {
    ...
}
```

You should ***immediately*** stop using your code due to injection vulnerabilities as well as the deprecation of `mysql_` functions.  Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Depending on how many records you are updating and how many connections you are making, it may slow down your script.

If you wish to `INSERT` records, you need to be using prepared statements.

Also, I don't understand the commnet `// Mysql_num_row is counting table row` in your `save_language` function as you are not using the number of rows from the result anywhere.

Comment: Obviously there are some comments in there that make sense.  I recycle code a lot.  I am mostly concerned with the following: foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
                $sql="UPDATE `languages` SET `value`='$value' WHERE `id`='$key'";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                }   Is there a better way to loop through the $_POST and is the query statement okay where it resides.